# Viewing ISO9660/Joliet/UDF Windows attributes?

Tags: linux, windows, data-cd, optical-media

How can I see the Windows attributes on optical discs?

Examples:

```
* Hidden.
* Read-Only.
* System file.
```

The ACL tools on Linux still do not display the *hidden* attribute for instance.

Comment: I see the downvoting troll is active again, there is neiter a reason to downvote your question not to downvote may answer.

Comment: @schily I did not downvote your answer.

Comment: @schily Actually, I have been attacked by downvoting trolls myself. Read comments: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/402102/why-do-aging-desktop-pcs-need-multiple-starting-attempts?noredirect=1#comment988976_402102.

Answer (score 3):

These filesystems neither support ACLs nor Windows file attributes.

Readonly is a standard filesystem "attribute" that is used on UNIX before DOS existed...

"hidden" is the only windows file attribute that is supported by the filesystems named by you.

Since UNIX does not know a "hidden" file attributes but rather hides files that have a name starting with a dot, a "hidden" attribute on files cannot be honored on UNIX.

This applies to the UNIX filesystem "ZFS" as well. ZFS supports Windows file attributes only for the SMB exports to Windows clients.

If you like to check which files on a ISO-9660 filesystem have the hidden attribute set, use the UNIX program `isoinfo` on the filesystem image.

Call:

```
isoinfo -i filesystem.iso -l
```

and check the numbers directly before the `]`. If this number is odd, the hidden attribute is set on a file.

Comment: Disclaimer: I have not downvoted this.

Comment: I have a CD-ROM where files are indicated as hidden by Windows but not by Linux. Filenames do not start with dot.

Comment: @neverMind9: OK, I added information related to the hiden bit in ISO9660. If you have such problems with power supplies, it is most likely a dead electrolyte capacitor.

Comment: I will try out `isoinfo` out now.

Comment: Actually, despite ISO9660 is write-protected by design, files can have a seperate Windows write protection attribute.